# KMM: Compilation failed: Unexpected IrType kind: KIND_NOT_SET

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm trying to run tests in the shared library.

**Setup** (versions should be the same for both machines - all are up to date as of today):

```
Kotlin 1.6.21 (tried 1.6.20 and 1.6.10)

OpenJDK 11.0.15 (via Homebrew)

IntelliJ
Build #IC-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.45 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

XCode 13.3.1 with command-line tools

macOS BigSur 12.3.1
```

**M1 Pro**

```
:cleanIosSimulatorArm64Test :iosSimulatorArm64Test --tests "com.example.shared.ConverterTest" --stacktrace
```

**Intel Core i9** (same error, just change "arm" for "x64")

```
:cleanIosX64Test :iosX64Test --tests "com.example.shared.ConverterTest"
```

```
> Task :linkDebugTestIosSimulatorArm64 FAILED
e: Compilation failed: Unexpected IrType kind: KIND_NOT_SET
 * Source files: 
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.6.21 / Kotlin: 1.6.21
 * Output kind: STATIC_CACHE
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected IrType kind: KIND_NOT_SET
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.IrDeclarationDeserializer.deserializeIrTypeData(IrDeclarationDeserializer.kt:173)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.IrDeclarationDeserializer.deserializeIrType(IrDeclarationDeserializer.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.IrDeclarationDeserializer.deserializeIrClass(IrDeclarationDeserializer.kt:349)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.IrDeclarationDeserializer.deserializeDeclaration(IrDeclarationDeserializer.kt:775)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.IrFileDeserializer.deserializeDeclaration(IrFileDeserializer.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.FileDeserializationState.deserializeAllFileReachableTopLevel(IrFileDeserializer.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.ModuleDeserializationState.deserializeReachableDeclarations(BasicIrModuleDeserializer.kt:178)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.BasicIrModuleDeserializer.deserializeReachableDeclarations(BasicIrModuleDeserializer.kt:145)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker.deserializeAllReachableTopLevels(KotlinIrLinker.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker.findDeserializedDeclarationForSymbol(KotlinIrLinker.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker.getDeclaration(KotlinIrLinker.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.ExternalDependenciesGeneratorKt.getDeclaration(ExternalDependenciesGenerator.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.ExternalDependenciesGenerator.generateUnboundSymbolsAsDependencies(ExternalDependenciesGenerator.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ModuleGenerator.generateUnboundSymbolsAsDependencies(ModuleGenerator.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment$default(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.PsiToIrKt.psiToIr(PsiToIr.kt:180)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$psiToIrPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$psiToIrPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanDriverKt.runTopLevelPhases(KonanDriver.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:412)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:411)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profileIf(Util.kt:22)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profile(Util.kt:16)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion.mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer(K2Native.kt:411)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2NativeKt.mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer(K2Native.kt:666)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$daemonMain$1.invoke(main.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$daemonMain$1.invoke(main.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.daemonMain(main.kt:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinToolRunner.runInProcess(KotlinToolRunner.kt:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinToolRunner.run(KotlinToolRunner.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.CacheBuilder.ensureDependencyPrecached(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:962)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.CacheBuilder.ensureDependencyPrecached(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:887)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.CacheBuilder.buildCompilerArgs(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:1026)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinNativeLink.compile(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':linkDebugTestIosSimulatorArm64'.
> Compilation finished with errors
* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 16s
```

Comment: I suggest you [report it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) including a sample project to reproduce it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We encounter the same problem when running on Xcode, it was caused by upgrading the third party libraries, and one of the library need Kotlin 1.7 beta.

You can check what you have done before encounter the problem, if you manage you code with codebase, you can compare the codes between different commits and try to find the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 22):

If you're using kotlinx.datetime, you should set the version to 0.3.2.

I had the same problem, because the new version 0.3.3 requires Kotlin 1.7.0-Beta.

Comment: Thnaks!  This was exactly issue here!